# Heisenberg's equations of motion dynamical system

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hamiltonian-formalism, hamiltonian, phase-space, complex-systems

A quick question about Heisenberg's equations of motion:

$$i\hbar\dot{x} = [x,H],\qquad i\hbar\dot{p} = [p,H],$$

where $H$ is the Hamiltonian. I realize that strictly, $x$ and $p$ are operators, but can this be considered a dynamical system on phase space: $(x,p) \in \mathbb{R}^2$? Or, is that not allowed? I am motivated by the Wikipedia example of the Harmonic oscillator: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenberg_picture#Commutator_relations

They have solved for $x(t)$ and $p(t)$ here, like you would for a dynamical system.

Comment: Perhaps it would be useful to look at the Ehrenfest theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ehrenfest_theorem

Comment: Hi. I'm not seeing how the Ehrenfest theorem applies. Can you please elaborate? Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps I don't fully understand what exactly do you ask about, but the Ehrenfest theorem establishes the analogy between Heisenberg's equations of motion for operators and Hamilton equations for dynamic variables.

Comment: I'm simply asking if Heisenberg's equations of motion constitute a dynamical system, where ${x,p} \in \mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: Yes. Behold the [trajectories--Braunss](http://aip.scitation.org/doi/abs/10.1063/1.4984592).

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, the Heisenberg Eq. of motion
$$\dot{x}= i/\hbar[x,H],\ \dot{p} = i/\hbar[p,H]$$
describes how the dynamical variables of the system evolve in the Heisenberg picture. That is to say, x and p here are dynamical variables. However, they are "quantum" (operators), not "classical" (c-numbers) ones. In classical physics, x and p constituent a phase space since they are just numbers. However, in QM, the phase space is replaced by the Hilbert space whose state vectors are acted by physical operators. So, we cannot think x and p as a pair of real numbers anymore.